# Remove All Same id tr in table

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
<table>
<tr id="Name"></tr>
<tr id="Name"></tr>
<tr id="Name"></tr>
<tr id="Name"></tr>
<tr id="Name"></tr>
<tr id="address"></tr>
</table>
```

This is my problem. I want to remove all `tr` whose `id` is `Name` without using any loop.

Here is my code

```
jQuery('#Name').remove();
```

Comment: `Id` should be unique.  If snippet proposed by you does not work, this is the reason.  Use classes, e.g. `<tr class="Name"></tr>`.

Comment: yes i knew that ids should be unique but this is problem

Comment: You can't remove multiple elements except by using a loop (unless you want to do utterly insane serialisation to a string, then regular expression it, then parse the string back to DOM).

Answer (score 2):

Yopu better use some class instead of id as id is supposed to be unique for the elements in dom.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JMwXJ/1/)**

```
$('.someclass').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `ID` attribute, if it is not an identifier! An identifier has to be unique throughout the document or you get errors like you have.

If multiple elements should share some property (like in your case being selectable all together), use other attributes for that like [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset), [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name) (sometimes) or [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-class).

In your case you want to use the name or class attribute. In case you decide to use the class attribute, the JS could look like the following:

```
jQuery('.Name').remove();
```

With this HTML

```
<table>
 <tr class="Name"></tr>
 <tr class="Name"></tr>
 <tr class="Name"></tr>
 <tr class="Name"></tr>
 <tr class="Name"></tr>
 <tr class="address"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ids are unique, you cannot use same Id twice, however you can use same class 'n' number of times

```
<table>
<tr class="Name"></tr>
<tr class="Name"></tr>
<tr class="Name"></tr>
<tr class="Name"></tr>
<tr class="Name"></tr>
<tr id="address"></tr>
</table>

<script>
   jQuery('.Name').remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery attribute selector to find elements:

**Don't use id for more than one element in same document.**

```
$("tr[id='Name']").remove()
```

Demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVErG/1/)